# Make gdb use less memory

Tags: linux, gdb

gdb uses way too much memory on my Linux machine - I've allocated 2GB to this LXC virtual machine, but that's not enough.

Is there anything I can do apart from selectively uninstalling `-debuginfo` packages, which will effectively blind me if a problem turns out to involve those packages?

Comment: It is probably not `gdb` itself that uses so much memory. And the debuginfo packages are using disk space, not memory... Did you try using a real Linux distribution (without the overhead and inconvenience of a LXC virtual machine) on your desktop or laptop ?

Comment: debuginfo packages use memory when they are read in fully. It looks like I'm hitting a gdb bug.

Comment: But very often you don't need the debuginfo variants of system packages to find a bug in your own program. You only need to compile your own source code with `gcc -Wall -g` ! By the way, GDB 7.4 has been recently released. Did you try to compile and install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to [an issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=787487) in a CVS version of gdb. Downgrading gdb solved it.